# Displaying and drawing items in 3D in Qt

Tags: qt4, 3d

Is there any possibility to display and or to draw items in 3D in Qt without using the OpenGL part of Qt? For each of the items I want to visualize I can calculate the x, y and z coordinates of all the points that the item contains.

I would like to have something like QGraphicsView only in 3d if that is possible.

Comment: What sort of items are they? Widgets? Polygons? Just points?

Comment: some sort of lines actually. but i am calculating the coordinates of the points that each line contains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible.

You can grab the source code of this widget [PictureFlow](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/PictureFlow?content=75348) and see how it's done. 
Here is [another link to PictureFlow](http://code.google.com/p/pictureflow/)